# Coping from .txt file to excel I lose about 1340 lines from 61787, where do they disappear to?

Tags: excel

The txt file is filled with data I've extracted from some json's in this format:

```
filename|title_of_article
```

I've made sure that all of them have a title so no empty strings there.

When I copy this information into excel with the text to columns option set to "|" only.

The information is split properly into 2 columns however I end up losing about 1340 lines along the way. How does that happen?

When I do the same but do not set the Text to column options beforehand I copy everything to excel. I lose no lines.

Where does this problem come from?

I ran a vlookup and here are some of the lines that didn't copy in the first way:

[image]

as far as I can see there is nothing special about them.

Comment: probably the text to columns is generating some extra lines and either replacing the data that is in there (you should get a message when this happens though) or maybe have you go over the limit for an older version of excel? It seems you are not exceeding it, but the limit of rows for excel 2007 is 65536 for instance

Comment: a sample of the data would be helpful. And make sure there are no | present in the data on which you don't want to split

Comment: @Chrisvdberge I've made sure there are no | in the data as if there were they would push information into next columns, but there is nothing in them. Also I'm using office365 so its a pretty recent version.

Comment: @Chrisvdberge I'm intrigued by the possibility of excel overwriting lines, but I can't figure out how that could be happening. Is there a series of symbols that excel would interpret this way? I also added an example of some of the missing lines in the original post.